# Learn python 3 the hard way Ex46 instructions not clear

Tags: python-3.x, filesystems, python-venv

In excercise 46, it says

> When you are done setting all of this up, your directory should look like mine here:
>
> ```
> skeleton/  
>     NAME/  
>         __init__.py  
>     bin/  
>     docs/  
>         **setup.py**  
>     tests/  
>         **NAME_tests.py**  
>         __init__.py
> ```

...but he never said how to save these files inside the virtual directory.
How do I make a `.py` file and save it inside this `venv` directory?

I can't find the files and folder structures in windows explorer so I have no clue as to where to save.

I am stuck.

Thanks a lot for you help.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're confusing the use of [venv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) with the layout of your code in a project structure. You shouldn't be putting your Python code and modules in a `venv` generated directory. You didn't mention what OS you're using but here is the general workflow I use on OSX.

1. I put all of my `venv` environments in `$HOME$/.venv`. So I'd generate a `venv` environment like `python -m venv venv ~/.venv/skeleton` or you might have to use `python3 -m venv venv ~/.venv/skeleton` depending on your OS.
2. You would then activate the `venv` environment by `source ~/.venv/skeleton/bin/activate`
3. You'd then create your project like LPTHW says in a directory like `$HOME$/projects/skeleton`